# Facebook auth dialog only partially localized

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, authentication, localization

I'm using the latest Facebook IOS SDK to publish messages on the wall of my iPhone app's users.

Problem is my App has a different name in French and English.
So here's what I did so far:

- Went to https://developers.facebook.com
- Edited my FB Application, clicked on "Translate"
- Translated all Phrases from English to French
- Accepted all Translations
- Went to the dashboard and published the "French (France)" Language (although the "Translation / Approval Progress" was 0% for some reasons)

When I go on the "Auth Dialog" section of the FB app parameters and click on "Preview Dialog" it's all in French (all good!)

When I try it for real from my iPhone App, the Facebook text is in French, but My FB App title and description are still in English (booo)

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did end up creating 2 FB Apps, one in French, one in English. In the ios App I just check the user language and call the correct App Id...

If anybody has a better solution I'm interested!